# Combine occurrences of "C" when value of "A" and "B" match previous row

Tags: excel, concatenation, vba

Really hope you can help because i'm going blind on this issue. My spreadsheet has 20 columns and around 20,000 rows. Many rows are duplicates in all but 1 column and I need to Concatenate all the variables from that 1 column, where the rows match. My data is in order, so all duplicate rows are together and currently i have a macro but have to select a range by hand, which is slow.

My question is, can I run a VBA/formula that will match each duplicate partial row within a whole sheet, then concatenate the unique cell of those rows? please see my simplified example.

[image: simple example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should do the job; I'm sure this question will be closed for being off-topic (or migrated to Stack Overflow, where it actually belongs):

```
Sub GatherCountries()
'''Subroutine to loop through rows of column A and concatenate data of column C to column D,
'''when row - 1 == row

'Declare local variable types
Dim worksheetName As String
Dim rowNumber, rowEndNumber As Integer
Dim pasteCell As Range

'Declare local variables
worksheetName = ActiveSheet.Name
rowEndNumber = FindLastRow(worksheetName) 'Function call to function defined below

'Loop through each row, starting at line 2 as header is line 1
    For rowNumber = 2 To rowEndNumber
        With Worksheets(worksheetName) 'Reduce amount of unnecessary repitition
            'Case where cell Ax and Bx equal Ax-1 and Bx-1
            If .Cells(rowNumber, 1) = .Cells(rowNumber - 1, 1) And _
            .Cells(rowNumber, 2) = .Cells(rowNumber - 1, 2) Then
                pasteCell.Value = pasteCell.Value & ", " & .Cells(rowNumber, 3) 'Concatenate country to existing string
            'Case where cell Ax and Bx does not equal Ax-1 and Bx-1, loop will always enter this first
            Else
                Set pasteCell = .Cells(rowNumber, 4) 'Set the cell where concatenation should take place
                pasteCell.Value = .Cells(rowNumber, 3) 'Populate concatenation cell with first entry of country
            End If
        End With
    Next rowNumber
End Sub

Function FindLastRow(ByVal SheetName As String) As Long
'''Function to return the last row number of column A

    Dim WS As Worksheet

    On Error Resume Next
    Set WS = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName)
    FindLastRow = WS.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=WS.Cells(1), searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```

With some more code it is possible to look up which columns contain the values to check and the values to concatenate, but given the structure of the example in the question, this will do the job as asked:

Input:

[image: CountriesGatheringExcelInput]

Output, after code has ran:

[image: CountriesGatheringExcelOutput]

Comment: Sorry for the wrong location, was doing some GIS stuff as well !

Comment: Wow, looking through that, its so much more simple than I had been trying. I'll have a go but thanks so much for your help